# CZ-5 plus YZ-2 put SJ-17 in GEO - third stage or separate spacecraft?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, geostationary, upper-stage, china, long-march

- CZ-5 = [Long March 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_March_5)
- YZ-2 = [Yuanzheng 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuanzheng-1)
- SJ-17 = [Shijian 17](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/sj-17.htm)

[Gunter's Space Page says](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/sj-17.htm):

> SJ 17 (Shijian 17) is a Chinese experimental satellite flown on the maiden [CZ-5/YZ2](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau/cz-5.htm) launch.
>
> It is reportedly carrying out experiments with ion propulsion for station keeping.
>
> The satellite will be **directly inserted into geostationary orbit by the YZ-2 upper stage of the launch vehicle.** (my emphasis)

CZ-5 [has two stages according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_March_5), and second stage uses a pair of LH2/LOX restartable [YF-75D engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YF-75D). According to the Spaceflight 101 article [China’s Long March 5 Heavy-Lift Rocket achieves full Success in Inaugural Mission](http://spaceflight101.com/long-march-5-inaugural-launch-success/):

> The two engine nozzles began glowing bright orange again when the second stage re-started on a burn of just over four minutes to boost the stack into a highly elliptical sub-GTO-type orbit. Loud cheers emerged when the Yuanzheng-2 upper stage separated from the booster right at the half-hour mark into the flight, marking Mission Success for the Long March 5 rocket.
>
> Assuming control of the flight, Yuanzheng-2 immediately fired its hypergolic main engine for a short supplementary burn to raise the high point of the orbit to Geostationary Altitude at around 36,000 Kilometers. Next was a coast phase of around five and a half hours to allow YZ-2 to climb to the apogee of the orbit so that its second burn can circularize the orbit and reduce its inclination to reach a Geostationary Orbit for spacecraft separation at 18:57 UTC.

The hypergolic-fueled Yuanzheng-2 seems to be considered an "upper stage", and yet, separation is considered the completion of the Long March 5's mission. Is the YZ-2 considered a 3rd stage?

*How many stages does the Long March 5 actually have?* Two, or three?

---

[image]

**above:** Long March-5 Rocket from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Long_March_Rocket_at_Launchpad.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Honda Civic is a two axle vehicle. It can tow a trailer. When it's towing a trailer, Civic-plus-trailer is functionally a three axle vehicle.

There's no essential difference between a spacecraft with propulsion and a rocket stage.

In this case, Long March 5 is a two-stage rocket because it's designed and built separately from the YZ stage.

Long March 5 + YZ is functionally a three stage rocket.

Comment: A good point, though it would be interesting to distinguish whether the "upper stage" has some input into the control of events on the previous stages, such as separation, or is a pure passenger ejected by the previous stage. As an example, and please correct me if I am wrong, my understanding is that the Briz upper stage of the Proton follows the "control" model, delivered satellites follow the "passenger" model.