# Is the SS-520-5 both a floor wax and a desert topping? Can it be considered both a sounding rocket and an orbital vehicle?

Tags: terminology, launch-vehicle, sounding-rocket, jaxa

The answer to [If there "won't be" rockets to launch individual cubesats, then why did JAXA build exactly that? (SS-520-xx)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37909/12102) begins

> The SS-520-5 launcher is not intended to be an operational vehicle.

To my knowledge it has once successfully launched a cubesat, and that was the end of the project (thought I could be wrong).

- [Will JAXA try again to launch TRICOM-1 with the "world's smallest orbital rocket" SS-520-4 again?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22471/12102)
- [How small could an orbital rocket be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18789/12102)
- [Do launchers using only solid propellant exist?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26693/12102)
- [Has there ever been a completely solid fuelled orbital rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51777/12102)
- [Why isn't there a rocket to launch a single cubesat?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36261/12102)

There's a discussion under [What is the smallest object our current technology is capable of launching into space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/56217/12102) where I suggest the SS-520-5 *could be considered as* a sounding rocket that (barely) managed to put a few kg payload into orbit and suggested that vice grips used once as a hammer don't cease to be vice grips.

But there's some pushback that I'm wrong and the SS-520-5 should not be considered as a sounding rocket.

**Question:** Is the SS-520-5 both a floor wax and a desert topping?<sup>1</sup> Can it be considered both a sounding rocket and an orbital vehicle?

The high thrust/weight ratio at each stage and extremely high accelerations suggest to me that you could significantly increase the payload mass and put that payload on a sounding rocket trajectory to do sounding rocket research. It certainly seems one could think of it as a sounding rocket with the potential to reach orbit; is that wrong of me?

Addressing the "floor wax and a desert topping" aspect:

- [CZ-5 plus YZ-2 put SJ-17 in GEO - third stage or separate spacecraft?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18939/12102)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Series_(rocket_family)#SS-520

---

<sup>1</sup>See *New Shimmer* below (still can't find a video)

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Saturday_Night_Live_commercial_parodies#N
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certs#Certs_advertising

Comment: I'm struggling with how this isn't opinion based. "Ask not the Elves for counsel, for they will say both yes and no."

Comment: @OrganicMarble your answer to the above-linked "CZ-5 plus YZ-2 put SJ-17 in GEO" question says something similar. Let's give it a day or two to see how others respond to "Can it be considered both...?" I know at least one person has [something definitive](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/56217/what-is-the-smallest-object-our-current-technology-is-capable-of-launching-into#comment189094_56217) to say about it, as an answer post it will reach a wider audience, and since I was called "dishonest" there I think it's good to put this under a magnifying glass.

Comment: One person can consider it to be a sounding rocket, another can consider it not to be. I don't consider such things to be a fit topic for Stack Exchange. Perhaps you consider it to be? (See what I did there?)

Comment: This almost feels more appropriate for Meta

Comment: Reminder: This site is frequented by many people with vastly different cultural backgrounds, many of whom will not understand a reference to a particular comedy sketch aired in 1976. Without that understanding, the title question is nonsensical and baffling.

Comment: The best sounding rocket ever was, of course, the [Saturn I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_I_SA-2).

Comment: @RussellBorogove I do have a footnote to help with that, but it's certainly possible not everybody reads all the way through my questions. I do have two more links [in this post](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/743/12102) perhaps I should add them as well.